# How to sort a nested array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting

I have an array of objects:

```
entities: [
  {
    name: "zBroomsticks PTY",
    id: 34098365,
    entityType: "personal",
    facilities: [
      {
        type: "Home loan",
        account: "032654 987465",
        existing: true,
        modified: "04/12/2018",
        limit: 100000
      },
      {
        type: "Credt card",
        account: "032654 987465",
        existing: false,
        modified: "04/12/2018",
        limit: 200000
      },
      {
        type: "Credt card",
        account: "032654 987465",
        existing: false,
        modified: "04/12/2018",
        limit: 10000
      },
      {
        type: "Credt card",
        account: "032654 987465",
        existing: false,
        modified: "04/12/2018",
        limit: 10000
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Mr John Doe -3409865, Mrs Jane Doe -34098365",
    id: 34098365,
    entityType: "business",
    facilities: [
      {
        type: "Overdraft",
        account: "032654 987465",
        existing: false,
        modified: "04/12/2018" ,
        limit: 10000
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Mr Jack",
    id: 34098365,
    entityType: "mixed",
    facilities: [
      {
        type: "Overdraft",
        account: "032654 987465",
        existing: false,
        modified: "04/12/2018",
        limit: 10000
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to sort this in a specific order:

1. `entity.name`: in alphabetical ascending order.
2. `entity.entityType`: 1. personal 2. business 3. mixed
3. `entity.facilities.limit`: descending order

This is the code I've got so far:

```
sortData(entities) {
    var order = {
      entityType: { personal: 2, business: 1 }
    };

    return entities.map(ent =>
      entities.sort(
        (a, b) =>
          a.name - b.name ||
          order.entityType[a.facilities.entityType] - order.entityType[b.facilities.entityType]
      )
    );
}
```

I know how to perform the name sorting but cannot find an approach for 2 & 3?

[Link to code](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/dimitri-a/accordeon)

Comment: The `limit` is only to sort the `facilities` array, or do you expect it to affect the outer array `entities` too?

Comment: Just the facilities array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to order by `names` you can use [localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare). Second, there is no property `entityType` inside the `facilities` array but you are trying to access it. Now, one solution is to first use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get a new array where the `facilities` array are ordered by the `limit` property, then you can sort the new array returned by `map()` first by `names` and second by the `entityType` property, something like this:

```js
const input = [{name:"zBroomsticks PTY",id:34098365,entityType:"personal",facilities:[{type:"Home loan",account:"032654 987465",existing:true,modified:"04/12/2018",limit:100000},{type:"Credt card",account:"032654 987465",existing:false,modified:"04/12/2018",limit:200000},{type:"Credt card",account:"032654 987465",existing:false,modified:"04/12/2018",limit:10000},{type:"Credt card",account:"032654 987465",existing:false,modified:"04/12/2018",limit:10000}]},{name:"Mr John Doe -3409865, Mrs Jane Doe -34098365",id:34098365,entityType:"business",facilities:[{type:"Overdraft",account:"032654 987465",existing:false,modified:"04/12/2018",limit:10000}]},{name:"Mr Jack",id:34098365,entityType:"mixed",facilities:[{type:"Overdraft",account:"032654 987465",existing:false,modified:"04/12/2018",limit:10000}]},{name:"Mr Jack",id:34098365,entityType:"personal",facilities:[{type:"Overdraft",account:"032654 987465",existing:false,modified:"04/12/2018",limit:10000}]}];

let order = {
  entityType: {personal:1, business:2, mixed:3}
};

function sortData(entities)
{    
    let limitOrder = entities.map(e =>
    {
        e.facilities.sort((a, b) => b.limit - a.limit);
        return e;
    });

    return limitOrder.sort((a, b) =>
    {
        return a.name.localeCompare(b.name) ||
               order.entityType[a.entityType] - order.entityType[b.entityType];
    });
}

console.log(sortData(input));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Note, I have duplicate the object related to `name: "Mr Jack"` using a different `entityType` so you can see how the algorithm performs when there are two objects with equals `names`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
eType = {personal:1, business:2, mixed:3};

entities.sort((a,b) => {
   if(a.name>b.name) return 1;
   if(a.name<b.name) return -1;

   let et=eType[a.entityType]-eType[b.entityType];
   return et;   
})

entities.forEach(e=> e.facilities.sort((a,b)=> b.limit - a.limit ))
```

```js
let entities = [
        {
          name: "zBroomsticks PTY",
          id: 34098365,
          entityType: "personal",
          facilities: [
            {
              type: "Home loan",
              account: "032654 987465",
              existing: true,
              modified: "04/12/2018",
              limit: 100000
            },
            {
              type: "Credt card",
              account: "032654 987465",
              existing: false,
              modified: "04/12/2018",
              limit: 200000
            },
            {
              type: "Credt card",
              account: "032654 987465",
              existing: false,
              modified: "04/12/2018",
              limit: 10000
            },
            {
              type: "Credt card",
              account: "032654 987465",
              existing: false,
              modified: "04/12/2018",
              limit: 10000
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: "Mr John Doe -3409865, Mrs Jane Doe -34098365",
          id: 34098365,
          entityType: "business",
          facilities: [
            {
              type: "Overdraft",
              account: "032654 987465",
              existing: false,
              modified: "04/12/2018" ,
              limit: 10000
            }
          ]
        },
{
          name: "Mr Jack",
          id: 34098365,
          entityType: "mixed",
          facilities: [
            {
              type: "Overdraft",
              account: "032654 987465",
              existing: false,
              modified: "04/12/2018",
              limit: 10000
            }
          ]
        }
      ];
      
      
eType = {personal:1, business:2, mixed:3};

entities.sort((a,b) => {
   if(a.name>b.name) return 1;
   if(a.name<b.name) return -1;
   
   let et=eType[a.entityType]-eType[b.entityType];
   return et;   
})

entities.forEach(e=> e.facilities.sort((a,b)=> b.limit - a.limit ))

console.log(entities);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort your array with a order of priority `1`, `2` and finally `3`

`2` condition, you could use a `index` object to map `entityType` with their weight.

`3` Because you want to sort by `descending order`, then you have find minimum `limit` value in `facilities` list and compare it with other item.

```
let entities = [
  {
    name: "zBroomsticks PTY",
    id: 34098365,
    entityType: "personal",
    facilities: [
      {
        type: "Home loan",
        account: "032654 987465",
        existing: true,
        modified: "04/12/2018",
        limit: 100000
      },
      {
        type: "Credt card",
        account: "032654 987465",
        existing: false,
        modified: "04/12/2018",
        limit: 200000
      },
      {
        type: "Credt card",
        account: "032654 987465",
        existing: false,
        modified: "04/12/2018",
        limit: 10000
      },
      {
        type: "Credt card",
        account: "032654 987465",
        existing: false,
        modified: "04/12/2018",
        limit: 10000
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Mr John Doe -3409865, Mrs Jane Doe -34098365",
    id: 34098365,
    entityType: "business",
    facilities: [
      {
        type: "Overdraft",
        account: "032654 987465",
        existing: false,
        modified: "04/12/2018",
        limit: 10000
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Mr Jack",
    id: 34098365,
    entityType: "mixed",
    facilities: [
      {
        type: "Overdraft",
        account: "032654 987465",
        existing: false,
        modified: "04/12/2018",
        limit: 10000
      }
    ]
  }
];


const entityIndex = { personal: 1, business: 2, mixed: 3 };

let result = entities.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.name > b.name) return -1;
  if (a.name < b.name) return 1;

  let et = entityIndex[a.entityType] - entityIndex[b.entityType];
  if (et != 0) return et;

  const aMinLimit = Math.min(...a.facilities.map(i => i.limit));
  const bMinLimit = Math.min(...b.facilities.map(i => i.limit));

  return bMinLimit - aMinLimit;

})

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```